# segfault reading wide-oriented stream with locale settings

Tags: c, locale

I have problem in program with locale and reading from stdin with `fgetws` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

static const int N = 2;

int main(void) {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wchar_t data[N];
  fgetws(data, N, stdin);
  printf("%ls\n", data);
  /* fclose(stdin); */
  return 0;
}
```

When input is long enough (5 or more chars) I get segfault if I don't close `stdin` before `return`. Why is that? What is wrong with this program?

Comment: Just saw that.  Comment deleted.

Comment: data is not null terminated.  You will need to null terminate it to print it.

Comment: Why I do? From glibc's manual: `fgetws (wchar_t *WS, int COUNT, FILE *STREAM)` You must supply COUNT wide characters worth of space in WS, but the number of characters read is at most COUNT - 1. The extra character space is used to hold the null wide character at the end of the string.

Comment: The code looks OK. Except the `printf` thing that looks fishy. Have you tried some `w` versions of it? MS might have some screwed up implementation of `%ls`..(is it MS, btw??)

Comment: No problems on machine with gcc 5.2 and glibc-2.21. The problem reveals with glibc-2.22

Answer (score 1):

Suspect `fgetws(data, 2, stdin)` is broken.

`fgetws()`, using such a small buffer should, at most, read 1 `wchar_t` from `stdin` and append a termanting `(wchar_t) '\0'`.

As usual, when code fails mysteriously, best to check return from the functions to see if they are as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

static const int N = 2;

int main(void) {
  char *p = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  assert(p);

  wchar_t data[N];
  wchar_t *s = fgetws(data, N, stdin);
  assert(s); 

  int i = printf("%ls\n", data);
  assert(i == 2);

  i = fclose(stdin);
  assert(i == 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I figured out it's issue with glibc-2.22. With glibc-2.21 this code compiles and runs fine.